# How to loop in array and print all together without space in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm still on my learning curve in Javascript and trying to complete the last task on SoloLearn. I have to print out the input all together for example the first one "$hello$how$are$you$".

I've tried this so far, by doing a for loop and pushing it into an empty var and then join them together, but no luck so far. Any advice please?

```
class Add {
  constructor(...words) {
      var completeWord = "";
      this.words = words;
      this.print = function(){
        for(x=0;x<words.length;x++){
          completeWord.push[x];
        
          
        }

      }
      completeWord.join("");
      console.log(completeWord);
  }
  //your code goes here
  

}

var x = new Add("hehe", "hoho", "haha", "hihi", "huhu");
var y = new Add("this", "is", "awesome");
var z = new Add("lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet", "consectetur", "adipiscing", "elit");
x.print();
y.print();
z.print();
```

Answer (score 4):

Just `.join` the array by the separator, and add the separator to both ends of the resulting string:

```js
class Add {
  constructor(...words) {
    this.words = words;
  }
  print() {
    console.log('$' + this.words.join('$') + '$');
  }
}

var x = new Add("hehe", "hoho", "haha", "hihi", "huhu");
var y = new Add("this", "is", "awesome");
var z = new Add("lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet", "consectetur", "adipiscing", "elit");
x.print();
y.print();
z.print();
```

But JS isn't Java - there's no need for a class just to wrap a single method. If at all possible, use a plain function instead, it has less overhead and will make more structural sense:

```js
const add = (...words) => console.log('$' + words.join('$') + '$');

add("hehe", "hoho", "haha", "hihi", "huhu");
add("this", "is", "awesome");
add("lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet", "consectetur", "adipiscing", "elit");
```